# How can I add in post's the text "No content"

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, excerpt

How can I add in a post the words "No content available" if nothing is ritten

Example:
If there is no text added, i want to get "No content available" automated in my template.
I want to get for a specific Post Type, `Seriale`.

How can I make that?

In the template i have this

```
<?php 
    if (is_search()) 
        the_excerpt(); 
    else 
        the_content(__('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;')); ?>
<?php 
    if (is_page() or is_single()) 
        wp_link_pages(array(
            'before' => '<p><strong>Pages:</strong> ', 
            'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number'
        )); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you [searched](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badd_filter+%2Bthe_excerpt+is%3Aanswer) before asking? Also, what this code has to do with "No content"? What template is this? :::: Please, don't answer in the comments, update your Question: [edit]

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'check_empty_postcontent', 0, 99 ); // filter post content
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'check_empty_postcontent', 0, 99 ); // filter excerpt content

function check_empty_postcontent( $content ) {

    global $post;

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );

    return ( empty( $content ) && 'seriale' === strtolower( $post_type ) ) ?
        'No content available' : $content;

}
```

There are a lot of articles about that in the web.